# Enable a jframe when a vin

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, parent, frames

I made a JFrame in Java (Netbeans) with a button. When pressing that button another JFrame opens and the first frame has setEnabled to false. When I close my second Frame, I want the first one to be enabled again.... how can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Where is the code demonstrating a simple example of what you've attempted? Are you sure you aren't just looking for a modular JDialog?

Comment: Yes i did... do I have to close the topic (in one way or another)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have JFrame subclass objects, you can pass your first frame as an argument to your second frame, and enable the first frame again in the close event of your second frame.

MyJFrame class:

```
private MyJFrame alphaFrame;

public MyJFrame(MyJFrame alpha) {
    alphaFrame = alpha;
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
            alphaFrame.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}
```

You can then instantiate your second frame (from the first, I assume) with something like this:

```
MyJFrame secondFrame = new MyJFrame(this);
```